# Count from a JSON file into python

Tags: python, json, object, count

```
[
{
"frame_id":2, 
 "filename":"sample_imgs/2.jpg", 
 "objects": [ 
  {"class_id":8, "name":"boat", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x":1547, "top_y":1126, "width": 298, "height": 149}, "confidence":0.348690}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 128, "top_y":1327, "width":  30, "height":  89}, "confidence":0.972903}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 179, "top_y":1332, "width":  26, "height":  72}, "confidence":0.689888}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x":  79, "top_y":1324, "width":  29, "height":  73}, "confidence":0.663020}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 520, "top_y":1374, "width":  40, "height":  79}, "confidence":0.657240}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 565, "top_y":1367, "width":  36, "height":  84}, "confidence":0.447690}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 521, "top_y":1355, "width":  34, "height":  41}, "confidence":0.412204}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 159, "top_y":1318, "width":  27, "height":  77}, "confidence":0.306808}
 ]
```

How can I parse the file and count the number of IDs present in the JSON file using Python?
The code i used displayed all the data, but id like something of narrowing down eg

```
"person": 7, 
"boat": 1
```

Here's my code

```
import json
from collections import Counter

with open('/home/output/result.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    c = Counter(k[4:] for d in data for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith('class_id'))
print(data)
print(json.dumps(c, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: The values you want are in the `name` element, why are you using `k.startswith('class_id')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [
{
"frame_id":2, 
 "filename":"sample_imgs/2.jpg", 
 "objects": [ 
  {"class_id":8, "name":"boat", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x":1547, "top_y":1126, "width": 298, "height": 149}, "confidence":0.348690}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 128, "top_y":1327, "width":  30, "height":  89}, "confidence":0.972903}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 179, "top_y":1332, "width":  26, "height":  72}, "confidence":0.689888}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x":  79, "top_y":1324, "width":  29, "height":  73}, "confidence":0.663020}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 520, "top_y":1374, "width":  40, "height":  79}, "confidence":0.657240}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 565, "top_y":1367, "width":  36, "height":  84}, "confidence":0.447690}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 521, "top_y":1355, "width":  34, "height":  41}, "confidence":0.412204}, 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"person", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x": 159, "top_y":1318, "width":  27, "height":  77}, "confidence":0.306808}
 ]
}]

import json
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(obj.get('name') for item in data for obj in item['objects'])
print(counter.most_common())
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(counter, f, indent=4
```

)

output

```
[('person', 7), ('boat', 1)]
```

data.json

```
{
    "boat": 1,
    "person": 7
}
```

This assumes you may have more than one frame in the JSON file and handles all frames at once. Of course you can convert `counter` to `dict`

Comment: Yes, there are multiple frame into this JSON. Will converting to dict would display me the   {
    "boat": 1,
    "person": 7
}

Comment: Yes, it will. But if you going to write to JSON file you don't need to. And `Counter` object has dict-like interface. Do it's really just a presentation issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how its possible to convert this and getting a HEX string instead of a python list using this solution?

Comment: I would suggest you ask separate question with the sample input and expected output.

Comment: While a modified solution of the above code worked as expected i cant represent while i try to print values above 255 that later generated in my JSON. i get a byte must be in range(0, 256) error. Bear in mind i converted the above tuple representation to a bytes string needed for my application. "print(bytes(str))"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data file `a.json`, you can use pandas and json to manipulate the data.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('a.json') as fi:
    jdata = json.load(fi)


df = pd.DataFrame(data=jdata[0]['objects'])
output = df['name'].value_counts().to_dict()
print(output)

with open('output.json','w') as fo:
    json.dump(output,fo,indent=4)
```

## output

```
{'boat': 1, 'person': 7}
```

Comment: Code is executing, but i dont get the print.

Comment: I was working in jupyter notebook. The edited code should work now.

Comment: I get the printout thank you, im having a module were i want to sent Lora packages and in my code i sent messages in the form of lora.sent("Hello"). When im pasting the lora.sent(json.dump(output,fo,indent=4)) i get the error of "Encoding without a string argument. Probably that  python list needs to be converted to a string or a hex.